# Silverlight MultiScaleImage control bug and CPU usage

Tags: silverlight, cpu-usage, multiscaleimage

**How to use animation and MultiScaleImage control on the same UserControl?**
What I have found that if you place a MultiScaleImage and animation on the same UserControl, you always get a high CPU usage. **Is that a MultiScaleImage control bug?** Here's a sample [project](http://dotnetgroup.lt/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Components.UserFiles/00.00.00.21.26.SL/PerfTest_5F00_2009_2D00_09_2D00_09_5F00_1.zip). (*just a grid, MultiScaleImageControl and a fading rectangle*)

**Why CPU usage is high?** When animation is playing, UserControl fires LayoutUpdated event and MultiScaleImage catches that event and redraws itself. So if MaxFrameRate=60 (default value), then MultiScaleImage every second redraws itself ~60 times (MultiScaleImage.LayoutUpdated gets fired ~60 times) causing high CPU usage:

- ~20% CPU, if MaxFrameRate=10
- ~40% CPU, if MaxFrameRate=30
- ~85% CPU, if MaxFrameRate=60 (default)

Shouldn't MultiScaleImage redraw itsef (or recalculate something CPU intensive) only on SizeChanged event? Otherwise why use this control if I can't use animation?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like now it's a known [bug](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/125312/308237.aspx) :)